# Is $\Delta u+f\in (H^1(\Omega))^*$ with $u\in H^1_0(\Omega)$ and $f\in L^2(\Omega)$?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be an open bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $\partial \Omega$ being $C^2$. Suppose $u\in H^1_0(\Omega)$, $f\in L^2(\Omega)$ and $\nu>0$. It is said in the *Navier-Stokes Equations* by Constantin and Foias (in the chapter about weak solutions of the Stokes Equations) that

> $\nu \Delta u+ f$ is a distribution in $H^{-1}(\Omega)$

where $H^{-1}(\Omega)$ is defined as the continuous dual of $H^1(\Omega)$ and 
$$
H_0^1(\Omega):=\overline{C_c^\infty(\Omega)}^{\|\cdot\|_{H^1(\Omega)}}.
$$

If $H^{-1}(\Omega)$ is defined as the dual of $H^1_0(\Omega)$, then I can see that
$$
\nu \Delta u+ f\in H^{-1}(\Omega).
$$

Would anybody tell me why in the case $H^{-1}(\Omega):=(H^1(\Omega))^*$, it is still true? (Or is this a mistake?)

Comment: How do _you_ see that the statement is true for the dual of $H^1_0$?

Comment: Looks like a mistake to me. The usual definition of $H^{-1}$ is the dual of $H^1_0$.

Comment: @WillieWong: If $H^{-1}(\Omega)$ is defined the dual of $H_0^1(\Omega)$, I learned from references that $\Delta$ is a map from $H_0^1(\Omega)$ to $H^{-1}(\Omega)$ and $L^2(\Omega)\subset H^{-1}(\Omega)$. (But in Constantin and Foias, the author explicitly states that $H^{-1}(\Omega)$ is defined as the dual of $H^1(\Omega)$).

Comment: The convention that gives $H^{-s} = (H^s)^*$ seems to be due to Lax; do the computations in [this set of notes](http://www.disconzi.net/Research/Linear_PDEs_negative_norms.pdf) and its references help?

Comment: @WillieWong: Thanks for the references. As I can see from that article, $L^2(\Omega)\subset (H^1(\Omega))^*$. What I'm not sure is if $\Delta$ maps functions in $H_0^1(\Omega)$ to $(H^1(\Omega))^*$.